# MMdet train error - "OSError: Only py/yml/yaml/json type are supported now!"

Tags: pytorch, object-detection, openmmlab

I'm new to object detection. I've just been able to get and run some code (https://github.com/CAMMA-public/SurgLatentGraph) However keep bumping into this error during training phase (not test)

command (taken from repo)
`mim test mmdet --checkpoint configs/models/mask_rcnn/lg_ds_mask_rcnn_no_recon.py work_dirs/lg_ds_mask_rcnn_no_recon/best_endoscapes_ds_average_precision_epoch_${EPOCH}.pth --show` 
Error:
OSError: Only py/yml/yaml/json type are supported now!

I verified the the package version numbers and environment variables. I was expecting a smooth test inference.